# Why does TCP work, when UDP does not?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, udp

The code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 11100;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    do {
    $out = socket_read($msgsock, 2048);

    if (!empty($out)) {
        if ($out == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        elseif ($out == 'shutdown') {
            socket_write($msgsock, 'plc down', 8);
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        else {
            switch ($out) {
                case "KABBE": $response = "Kabbe te!"; break;
                case "SZOPJ": $response = "Szopjal te!"; break;
                default: $response = "Ismeretlen parancs";
            }
            socket_write($msgsock, $response, strlen($response));
            break;
        }
    }
    } while (true);
socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

It works with TCP:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
```

but with UDP it's not working:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
```

The errors:

> Warning: socket_listen() [function.socket-listen]: unable to listen on socket [0]: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced. in C:\wamp\www\socket\socket.php on line 22
>   socket_listen() failed: reason: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.
>
> Warning: socket_accept() [function.socket-accept]: unable to accept incoming connection [0]: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced. in C:\wamp\www\socket\socket.php on line 27
>   socket_accept() failed: reason: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.

Answer (score 5):

Because TCP is connection oriented and UDP is not, and there are different APIs for UDP sockets. Have a look at [socket_recvfrom](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php) and [socket_sendto](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by editing Growl class from

```
 socket_sendto($sck, $data, strlen($data), 0x100, $this->address, $this->port);
```

to

```
 socket_sendto($sck, $data, strlen($data), 0x0, $this->address, $this->port);
```